# Zitterbewegung for massless particle

Tags: dirac-equation

Is it possible for a massless particle to undergo zitterbewegung? In massive Dirac theory the Zitterbewegung frequency comes out to be $2mc^2/\hbar$. It looks like the effect will vanish for a massless particle. But the effect is due to the interference between particle and antiparticle state which is also there for a massless particle. So what would be the outcome?